# Nginx Match Pattern Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

The url looks like this

/index.php?option=com_hwdmediashare&task=addmedia.upload&$1

I need to do a location matching the $1 query string to redirect to the proxy server for what ever is on the end of the url.

```
location ~* \.(php?option=com_hwdmediashare&task=addmedia.upload)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    expires 10s;
    max_ranges 0;
    charset utf-8;
    }
```

I tried the following but it did not work can anyone help ? I need the end of that url to redirect to the proxy server

Comment: been trying for hours still no luck :(

Comment: Maybe you should try with [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).@C0nw0nk